# Specified target element for preview in blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, file-upload, blueimp

The problem is that I can't find any example or tutorial that explains how to define a div element with unique `id` to make preview of an image after its `url` is received from the server. So, I tried following:

```
let i = 1;
$("#uploadForm").fileupload({
    url: 'url',
    add: function (e, data) {
        $('.targetDiv').clone().attr('id', 'target' + i).appendTo('#Images').show().append('<img src=""/>');
        data.submit();
        i++;
    },
    progress: function (e, data) {
        var progress = parseInt((data.loaded / data.total) * 100, 10) + '%';
        $('#target' + i).find('.progress-bar').animate({
            width: progress
        }).text(progress);
    },
    done: function (e, data) {
        $('#target' + i).find('img').attr('src', data.result.url).show();
    }
});
```

Maybe this is weird! Yeah, this doesn't works!
Actually, I want to make preview of first successful uploaded image in large resolution and others in smaller. So, how can i do this? thanks to any suggestion.

Comment: By the way, I finally found the proper tutorials!!
[link](https://www.sanwebe.com/2015/06/ajax-multi-file-upload-with-blueimp-php)

Comment: And this: [link](https://www.htmlgoodies.com/html5/javascript/html5-and-blueimp-jquery-file-upload-plugin-event-handling.html)